# Tkinter Dual Command for one Button

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm doing my GCSE's and this is one of the tasks that I have been given, (btw I'm not very good at this) I need help with putting two commands into one button on tkinter for python. Here is my Code

```
# --------------------- START OF SCRIPT ---------------------
# Imports
from tkinter import *
# Question 1
def rootclose():
    root.destroy()

def question1():
    q1 = Tk()
    q1.geometry("500x500+200+200")
    f1 = Frame()
    f1.pack(side=LEFT)
    f2 = Frame()
    f2.pack(side=RIGHT)
    q1l1 = Label(q1, text="Question 1", fg="Green")
    q1l1.pack()
    q1l2 = Label(q1, text="What Operating System Dose Your Phone Run?", fg="Green")
    q1l2.pack()

        def question2v1():
        q2v1 = Tk()
        a1.destroy()
        q2v1.geometry("500x500+200+200")
        q2v1l1 = Label(q2v1, text="", fg="Green")
        q2v1l1.pack()
        q2v1l2 = Label(q2v1, text="", fg="Green")
        q2v1l2.pack()
        b1 = Button(q2v1, text="Android")
        b2 = Button(q2v1, text="")
        b1.pack()
        b2.pack()
        q2v1.mainloop()


    def ios():
        q3 = Tk()
        q1.destroy()
        q3.geometry("500x500+200+200")
        q3l1 = Label(q3, text="Question 1", fg="Green")
        q3l1.pack()
        q3l2 = Label(q3, text="Did you select IOS", fg="Green")
        q3l2.pack()
        b1 = Button(q3, text="Android")
        b2 = Button(q3, text="IOS")
        b1.pack()
        b2.pack()
        q3.mainloop()


    q1b1 = Button(q1, text="Android", command=question2v1)
    q1b2 = Button(q1, text="IOS", command=ios)
    q1b1.pack()
    q1b2.pack()
    q1.mainloop()
# Tkinter startups
root = Tk()
# Size ect..
root.geometry("500x500+200+200")
#HelpBot
L1 = Label(root, text="Welcome To HelpBot", fg="Green")
L1.pack()
# StartButton
B1 = Button(root, text="Start!", command=question1 and rootclose)
B1.pack()

# END OF SCRIPT
root.mainloop()
```

I am specifically trying to fix this

> ```
> # StartButton
> B1 = Button(root, text="Start!", command=question1 and rootclose)
> B1.pack()
> ```

The And that I have put in the command section of the button will only run the Last function in this case "rootclose" and not bother with this first which in this case is "question1"

Comment: By the way i know my code is messy im only young :)

Answer (score 3):

Create a function to do your 2 commands, and make calling that the command that the button does.